# In-app purchase - different versions

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store, iap-hosted-content

I would like to add an in-app purchase with downloadable content hosted on Apple servers to my app. This purchase with its content will be updated with every new version of the app. The updated purchase will work only with the latest app version. In this case the owner of the older version will be able to purchase and download the new version content. How can I resolve the issue?

I see that an array of `SKDownload` is available in `SKPaymentTransaction`. Does it mean that all in-app purchase versions will be available for the app? In this case it would be enough to download only the version compatible with the app.

Another variant is to link a purchase version to an app version. If they don't match the customer will be offered to update the app before purchasing.